# "Harmonic map" versus "Minimal surface"

Tags: differential-geometry

This might be an extremely basic differential geometry question.
Are "Harmonic map" and "Minimal surface" related?  For instance in certain special dimension or situation, they might be the same thing?

Comment: If you have a (regular parametrized) surface $X\colon M \to \Bbb R^n$, $X = (X_1,\ldots, X_n)$, and $g_{ij} = \langle \partial_iX, \partial_jX\rangle = \lambda^2$ for some smooth function $\lambda$, then $X[M]$ is a minimal surface if and only if each component $X_i$ is a harmonic function.

Comment: Thanks!  So what does the condition $g_{ij}=\lambda^2$ actually mean?  The answer below by Gary seems to say that one only needs to assume "isometric immersion"

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}$ be two Riemannian manifolds and $f: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{N}$ be a smooth embedding. Then $f(\mathcal{M})$ is minimal if and only if the map $f$ is isometric and harmonic. If $dim(\mathcal{M})=2$, then  $f(\mathcal{M})$ is minimal if and only if the map $f$ is conformal and harmonic.

Answer (score -1):

They are generally different, but there is an interesting connection between them. A map $\varphi: M \to N$ between Riemannian manifolds is harmonic if the divergence of its differential vanishes (in an appropriately defined sense). Such maps are the extrema of an energy functional:
$$E(\varphi) = \frac{1}{2}\int_M |d\varphi|^2 \ d\mu_g,$$
where $d\mu_g$ is the volume form on $M$. One can of course come up with a differential equation in local coordinates. So, the quality of being harmonic is a property of maps.

A minimal surface is essentially a surface that locally minimizes its area. So, this is a property of a surface. There are a number of different ways to express this requirement. One way would be to say that it is minimal if it can locally be expressed as the graph of a solution of the minimal surface equation:
$$\mathrm{div}\  \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}} =0.$$
An interesting connection was mentioned in the comments. Namely, that an isometric immersion of a Riemannian manifold into Euclidean space $X:M \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is minimal if the coordinate functions $X_j$ are harmonic on $M$ for each $j$.

Edit (to address comment): They still won't be the same, but they could be seen as connected. In order to do that, we would have to define a "minimal curve". I'm not sure that this is commonly done in the way that minimal surfaces are considered; I don't think that they'd be terribly interesting.

Aside: I suppose that the isoperimetric problem might be considered to involve a certain kind of "minimal curve"

In analogy with a minimal surface, one might perhaps define a "minimal curve" (in the plane) to be a curve with vanishing curvature. This would just be a straight line. This could be considered minimal in a sense; a line segment is the curve of minimal length connecting two points. So, we might say that lines are "minimal curves".

What about harmonic functions of one variable? Such a function would satisfy
$$0 = \Delta u(x) = \partial_x^2 u.$$
We can just integrate this to get the solutions:
$$u(x) = Ax+B,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants. So, in this case the graph of a harmonic function would yield a "minimal curve".

So, in this setting they still aren't the same thing, but they're related. A harmonic function is a function, while a "minimal curve" is a curve. These are distinct types of objects. However, using the definitions we came up with, the graph of a (1d) harmonic function is a minimal curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!  So if M is a curve, are the two notions identical?